# IE8: Submit a form within an iFrame does not work

Tags: forms, iframe, symfony1, internet-explorer-8, csrf

I have a frameset with an iFrame with a form in it.
When I submit the form IE8 does not send the form values. Firefox does.
Without the ambient frameset it works.

This is my code:

**form.php:**

```
<form method="post" action="doit.php" name="myForm" id="myForm" target="myFrame">
  <input type="hidden" id="customer__csrf_token" name="customer[_csrf_token]" value="0136dba17fc1a81dc2c3b44dcb513712" />
  ...
  <a onClick="document.myForm.submit();">Send</a>
</form>
```

**site.html:**

```
<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame" src="form.php" frameborder="0" >foo</iframe>
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
    <frameset rows='100%,*'>
      <frame name='target' src='site.html'>
      <noframes>foo</noframes>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

I also tried to submit the form with these calls:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
document.forms['myForm'].submit();
parent.frames['myFrame'].document.forms['myForm'].submit();
<input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="send" />
```

Can you help me?

**EDIT:**

I found the problem. I use the symfony framework. symfony uses a hidden csrf token in combination with a cookie value to secure the form trasmission. For some reason in my case IE8 is not able to store this cookie. Now I removed the csrf token from the form to get it working correctly.

Comment: Understand that by removing the CSRF value from the form you are opening yourself up to CSRF attacks. This may or may not be a big deal depending on what the form is doing.

Comment: Thanks, your question and subsequent EDIT: pointed me in the direction of a bug i was experiencing as well. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF was not the main problem. The problem in my case was caused by the IE security settings. IE does not allow a.o. cookies from domains with an underscore in it.
My domain was **foo_bar.dev.domain.com**, after chaning it to **foo-bar.dev.domain.com** it worked, also with enabled CSRF.